In a social media app, Ethereum suffice the transaction costs?
I'm new to making a dapp, I'm thinking a social media app where the users can pay for the posts to tip or boost or whatever. Like, tipping 1 dollar to a user/post. Something similer to Steemit I guess, but more like Twitter (X).
Now, I wonder something: Wouldn't it be too much transaction costs if it uses Etherium/Solidity?
As I use Etherium to pay sometimes, I know how it much costs usually. Like as cheaper as 1.2 USD or so to as high as 8 bucks or so. (at least these recent days)
I mean, for a 1 dollar or 2 dollars tip, 1.2 dollars fees is not very reasoable. Right? Solana or Matic for example only costs < 0.01 USD, as a comparison.
Again, I barely know how dapps work. I hope I don't understand the things, because I want to use Solidity.
So, am I wrong? How the costs would work (the p2p small amount tip transactions) in such case? Thanks.

So you want to use solidity but don't want to use ethereum for the high gas cost? Then you can use any L2 blockchain that is EVM compatible. EVM is the ethereum virtual machine, and being compatible with it means that a smart contract written for ethereum works well also for the other blockchain (with only small differences). In particular it means you can use solidity, metamask, ... and all other tools developed for ethereum.
